# Filter wordpress query by checkboxes

Tags: wordpress, filter

I have a situation where I have a query with two different post types and I have to checkboxes on top with the names of post type. I wont by default those checkboxes to be checked and if one of theme is unchecked to remove that post type and the post affiliated to that post type from the query.

Answer (score 0):

This part is circumstancial, but you get the idea. Give the values to the ones that are/aren't checked.

```
if($checkboxone == '1') { 
    $types = array( 'typeone' )
}
if($checkboxtwo == '1') {
    $types = array( 'typetwo' )
}
if($checkboxtwo == '1' && $checkboxone == '1'){
    $types = array( 'typeone', 'typetwo' )
}
```

then plug that value into your WP_Query by some means like this. the documentation for it is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_.26_Status_Parameters)

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => $types );

// The Loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    //DO STUFF
endwhile;

// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Hi Alex
Thanks first of all for quick response.  I still could not fined solution to see which one was checked, I tried many solutions but nether of them seemed to work :( do you know any good solution for this?
here are some of theme:

Comment: Solution 1
<input type='checkbox' name='box[1]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[2]'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[3]'>

Php:
foreach ($_POST['box'] as $id=>$checked){
    if ($checked =='on')
}

Comment: Solution 2
<input type='checkbox' name='box[]' value='1'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[]' value='2'>
<input type='checkbox' name='box[]' value='3'>

Php:
foreach ($_POST['box'] as $id){
        //process your id
}

Comment: Solution 3
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box_1" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="check_box_1" value="1" />

Php:
if ($_POST['check_box_1']=='1') { /*Do something for ticked*/ }
else { /*Do something for unticked*/ }

Comment: Solution 4
<input name="rows[]" value="uniqueIdForThisRow" type="checkbox" />
<input name="rows[]" value="anotherId" type="checkbox" />

Php:
// $_POST['rows'] contains the values of all checked checkboxes, like:
// array('uniqueIdForThisRow', 'anotherId', ...)

foreach ($_POST['rows'] as $row) {
  if ($row == 'uniqueIdForThisRow') {
   // do something
   }
}